# How can I run the same process multiple times on the same core on parallel?

Tags: process, mpi, slurm

What I know:

- I can run the same process on multiple cores at the same time
- I can also run a specific process on a specific core by simply adjusting a flag on the terminal

What I would like to learn:

- I want to know how I can run an MPI process on the same core various times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of MPI do you have?

For openmpi 1.10 solution is:

```
mpiexec -np 4 --map-by ppr:2:core ./program
```

Here `4` is total number of processes, `2` is number of processes per core.

Comment: @pertmikheev is there a way to see how the processes are only being run on the particular core?

Comment: @abeltre1, with Open MPI, add `--report-bindings` to the `mpirun` options.

Comment: @HristoIliev I found that very helpful and this link as well, https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/kb_articles/parallel-job-execution-on-commodity-clusters/